# Client side validation entity framework mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation

I have model:

```
    public int EventID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You have to enter the name of the event")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You have to enter date of the event")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime,ErrorMessage="You have to enter valid date and time")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Sport")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You have to choose the sport")]
    public int SportID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "League /Competition")]
    public string SportText { get; set; }
```

and I have form to add events. 
When I leave date and name empty I get error message for both fields (in the view), but if I enter date and leave name empty it won't show me error message, instead it throws exception:

Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

I know I can insert try catch statement, but I don't get why client side validation doesn't work on "Name" property

Comment: Show use the part of the code where you do the .SaveChanges();

Answer (score 0):

The thing is your text box is passing an empty string value, making it pass the `Required` validation.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. I've tried adding Minimal length, but it doesn't work. And when I debug it value is null not "". And error is shown on both properties (Date and Name) if I leave both textboxes empty.